# Nested array is erroring as undefined, wheras this is available in debugging mode

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript object array of below Class (SitecoreItem). I am trying to access the Itemtags property of this object, in order to access the nested array in this object. Ultimately i want to change the values of nested array.

```
class SitecoreItem {
    Name: string;
    Path: string;
    GUID: string;
    Itemtags: TagItem[];
   }

  class TagItem{
    TagItemName: string;
    TagItemGUID: string;
    TagPath: string;
    Checked: boolean;
  }
```

I am using below code to access the nested array.

```
this.sampleItem.map((d)=>{
        if(d.GUID == itemId){
          d.Itemtags.map((f)=>{
              if(f.TagItemGUID == e.target.value)
              {
                  f.Checked = e.target.checked;
                  return f;
              }
              return f;
          })
          d.Name = d.Itemtags[1].TagPath;
          d.Name = "Test";
          return d;
        }
        return d;
      })
```

A problem which i am facing is "d.Itemtags" is erroring out saying it is undefined. But when I check this in debugger, i can see "d.Itemtags" is not undefined and this has a nested array in it.  this can be a silly issue but i am curious to know the issue and i would really appreciate if someone can catch what i am missing?

Screenshot showing the Itemtags is available and not undefined.

[image: Screenshot showing the Itemtags is available and not undefined.]

I have also trying accessing this array like d["Itemtags"] and getting the same error.

Error message:

> SampleComponentComponent.html:66 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Please don't paraphrase error messages. What is the **exact** error message? Use copy and paste. (I suspect it's not complaining about `d.Itemtags`, it's complaining about `d`.)

Comment: Your screenshot just tells us (and you) that sometimes, `d` and `d.Itemtags` are not `undefined`. But the error tells you sometimes one of them (probably `d`) **is**. That's what you need to debug. Put a conditional breakpoint on that if with the condition `d === undefined || d.Itemtags === undefined` and run your code until the breakpoint is triggered.

Comment: "SampleComponentComponent.html:66 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". This is the exact error messge. In my original code i am able to access property of "d" already, and this is why i can say it is complaining about d.Itemtags. I tried to put a condition as well (d.Itemtags === undefined) to check undefined and it is simply not passing that condition and that is saying that d.itemtags is somehow null. The strange thing is that in debugging mode i can see that d.Itemtags is an array with all values. Below is the orinal code, which i trimmed in order to easy to explain.

Comment: `this.sampleItem.map((d)=>{
        if(d.GUID == itemId){
          d.Itemtags.map((f)=>{
              if(f.TagItemGUID == e.target.value)
              {
                  f.Checked = e.target.checked;
                  return f;
              }
              return f;
          })
          d.Name = d.Itemtags[1].TagPath;
          d.Name = "Test";
          return d;
        }
        return d;
      })`

Comment: Code in the comments is often difficult to parse. You should consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68508742/edit) when you want to add more information.

Answer (score -1):

A jsfiddle snippet would help us understand better. From the question I understand few things.

1. I don't see you keeping a return statement for map. [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
this.sampleItem.map((d)=>{
        return d?.Itemtags?.map((f)=>{
        
          })
      })
```

2. You can achieve this using foreach and for as well. That would solve your confusion. [foreach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: i have updated the original question where i am returning the value. Just for make it short i trimmed the code earlier. Yes i can try foreach, but i am very curious that what i am doing wrong and how javascript can say this object as undefined when in debugging i can see it is already filled with correct values.